# How to order citations?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, bibliographystyle, multiple-citations

Assume I have cited a certain article first, but then recite it later as follows

```
This work \cite{citation1} and that research \cite{citation2,citation1,citation3}
```

Using

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

I get something like

```
This work [1] and that research [2,1,3]
```

Is it possible to automatically write the second citation in global reference order, that is, [1,2,3], independently of the order I write the arguments in `\cite{}`?

If not, is it possible to sort any multi-citation, like `\cite{citation2,citation1,citation3}`, by year of publication, if available?

Edit: I am using BibTeX

Comment: I assume you are using `bibtex`. Try loading the `cite` package (`\usepackage{cite}`). https://ctan.org/pkg/cite (If that doesn't help, please edit your question to include a compilable MWE so it is easier for others to help you).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three options depending on what bibliography package you are or are not using. Since you mention the `unsrt` bibliography style, I'm assuming you're using the default citation functionality of LaTeX (i.e., no package).

### Option 1

Load the `cite` package:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

...

\bibliography{your-bibfile}
```

The default option will be to both sort and compress references, so [2,1,3] will become [1-3]. If you don't want the compression use:

```
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

...

\bibliography{your-bib-file}
```

### Option 2

Load the `natbib` package, with the `[numbers,sort&compress]` options.  For this you will need to use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. If you don't need compression, just use `sort` instead of `sort&compress` as the sorting option.

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

...

\bibliography{your-bib-file}
```

### Option 3

Use `biblatex` and `biber` to process your bibliography:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{your-bib-file.bib}

...

\printbibliography
```

If you want compressed citations, use `style=numeric-comp`.